# SQL Contains Query Returning Different Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains

I have a simple query

```
SELECT *
FROM QTests
WHERE CONTAINS(QTestId, '18 ~ 14 ~ 10')
```

Each time I run it it returns more results.

Comment: The only way this could be happening is if the `QTests` table has some DML activity (inserts/updates/deletes) happening at the same time you keep querying.  In other words, something/someone must be changing the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, it is on my local machine with a local database.

Comment: Can we see some actual data samples here?  By "more results" I believe we are assuming "more rows" so it would be good to see the "before" and "after" of executions - and do it again like from SSMS where you just re-run the query.

Comment: What is the result of `select name, is_importing from sys.fulltext_catalogs` and `select name, has_crawl_completed, crawl_type_desc from sys.fulltext_indexes`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using FULLTEXT INDEX on `QTestId` Column , also this query will give you result based on '18 ~ 14 ~ 10' as a 1 variable and not 18 , 14 , 10 separately .

Answer (score 0):

I did not realise that the full text index was actually still populating so it was returning what was populated so far.